# MS-Access: sum up 2 values before building a pivot table

Tags: sql, ms-access

So somebody ordered cheese, beer, bread and cigarettes, and table `tblItems` looks like this:

```
iID  iName       iAmount  iPrice  iProductID  iOrderID    
------------------------------------------------------
1    cheese      1        2.99    11          7
2    can of beer 6        0.99    14          7
3    bread       1        2.25    15          7
4    cigarettes  1        6.99    16          7
```

Before feeding this order into a `TRANSFORM` query, I need to

- summarise all items with `iProductID = 11 OR iProductID = 15`
- name it as `food`
- and assign to it a `iProductID = 99`
- iProductIDs other that 14 or 99 are to be filtered out

I do not want to change the data in `tblItems` though.

I need it to look like this:

```
iID  iName        iAmount  iPrice  iProductID  iOrderID
-------------------------------------------------------
1    food         1        5.24    99          7
2    can of beer  6        0.99    11          7
```

I've been fiddling around for more than an hour and just can't seem to grasp it.

The filtering-part is easy.

```
SELECT * FROM tblItems WHERE iProductID = 11 OR iProductID = 99
```

It is the aggregating part that gives me headaches.

Can somebody please help and point me in the right direction?

Comment: It is highly unorthodox to put the *columns* of a table in rows and the *rows* in columns.  This makes your question harder than necessary to understand.

Comment: Thank you, rotated.

Answer (score 1):

You want an aggregation query:

```
select iif(i.productid in (11, 15), 99, i.productid) as productid,
       "food" as iName,
      sum(i.price) as price,
       i.orderid
from tblItems as i
where i.iproductid in (11, 15, 14)
group by iif(i.productid in (11, 15), 99, i.productid), i.orderid;
```

Comment: `can of beer`shouldn't be named as `food` though.